# Ursina Python Level Switch

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina, panda3d

When trying to go back to the main menu, it says 'menu' not defined whereas it has been used previously in other functions. This only happens when I press the 'escape' key to exit the level and go back to the main menu.

```py
from panda3d.core import loadPrcFile
loadPrcFile("/z/# Computer Science Project/Prototypes/Prototype 1/Config.prc")
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from ursina.shaders import basic_lighting_shader as bls
from levels.levels import *
from objects.objects import *

def showmainmenu():
    levelmenu.enabled=False
    #destroy(levelmenu)
    Wait(.1)
    menu.enabled=True

def quit():
    application.quit()

def playgame():
    menu.enabled=False
    #destroy(menu)
    Wait(.1)
    FirstLevel()

def loadlevelone():
    levelmenu.enabled=False
    #destroy(levelmenu)
    Wait(.1)
    FirstLevel()

def selectlevelmenu():
    menu.enabled=False
    #destroy(menu)
    Wait(.1)
    levelmenu.enabled=True

#def quitlevel():
    #menu.enabled=True


if __name__ == "__main__":


    app = Ursina(title="Sky Fighter")

    window.exit_button.enabled = False
    window.fps_counter.enabled = False
    window.fullscreen = False

    menu = Menu(enabled=True)
    menu.playbutton.on_click=playgame
    menu.levelsbutton.on_click=selectlevelmenu
    menu.quitbutton.on_click=quit

    levelmenu = LevelMenu()
    levelmenu.enabled=False
    levelmenu.backbutton.on_click=showmainmenu
    levelmenu.levelone.on_click=loadlevelone

    app.run()
```

THE ABOVE SHOWS main.py AND BELOW SHOWS levels.py

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.radial_menu import RadialMenu
from ursina.prefabs.radial_menu import RadialMenuButton
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from objects.objects import *
from main import quitlevel
from main import *

class FirstLevel(Entity):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = Timer()
        self.finished = False
        self.controller = FirstPersonController(speed = 10, jump_height = 5, jump_up_duration = 1, fall_after = 0.35, gravity = 1.5, x = -5, z = -5)
        self.sprint = False
        self.timed = False

        #self.pause_handler = Entity(ignore_paused=True)
        #self.pause_text = Text("PAUSED", origin=(0,0), scale=2, enabled=False)

        self.sky = Sky(parent=self)
        self.ground = Entity(model = "Plane",
            color = color.green,
            scale = (100,1,100),
            position = (0,0,0),
            texture = "Grass",
            collider = "box",
            parent=self)
        self.start = StartPlatform((0,0,0),(5,1,5))
        self.end = EndPlatform((21,6,21),(5,1,5))

        self.platform1 = Platform((7,2,7),(5,1,5))
        self.platform2 = Platform((14,4,14),(5,1,5))

    def timing(self):
        hit_info = raycast(origin = self.controller.world_position, direction=(0, -1, 0),ignore= (self.controller,Platform,self.ground), distance = .5, debug = False)

        #Detect whether the ray hits the start or end platforms
        hit = str(hit_info.entity)
        if hit == "start_platform" and self.timed != True and self.finished != True: #Select if the player is on the start platform while not timed or finished
            self.timed = True
        if hit == "end_platform" and self.timed == True: #Select if the player has reached the end and they are timed
            self.timed = False
            self.finished = True

        if self.timed:
            self.timer.t += time.dt #Add the time delta since the last frame
            self.timer.text = str(round(self.timer.t, 2)) #Set the timer text to the time
    
    def update(self):
        self.timing()
    
    #def pause_handler_input(self, key):
        #if key == "escape":
            #application.paused = not application.paused
            #self.pause_text.enabled = application.paused

    def input(self, key):
        #self.pause_handler.input = self.pause_handler_input
        if held_keys["left control"]:
            self.sprint = True
            self.controller.speed = 20
        if self.sprint and not held_keys["left control"]:
            self.controller.speed = 10
        if key == "enter":
            self.finished = False
            self.timed = False
            self.timer.text = "0"
            self.timer.t = 0
        if key == "backspace":
            quit()
        if key == "escape":
            
            self.enabled = False
```

This error is then displayed:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 49, in eventLoopTask
    self.doEvents()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 43, in doEvents
    processFunc(dequeueFunc())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 99, in processEvent
    messenger.send(eventName, paramList)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 337, in send
    self.__dispatch(acceptorDict, event, sentArgs, foundWatch)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 422, in __dispatch
    result = method (*(extraArgs + sentArgs))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ursina\main.py", line 189, in input
    entity.input(key)
  File "z:\# Computer Science Project\Prototypes\Prototype_3\levels\levels.py", line 73, in input
    quitlevel()
  File "z:\# Computer Science Project\Prototypes\Prototype_3\main.py", line 38, in quitlevel
    menu.enabled=True
NameError: name 'menu' is not defined
:task(error): Exception occurred in PythonTask eventManager
```